# C++ queue with dependencies

Tags: c++, c, queue, scheduled-tasks

I am looking for a prototype or implementation for a queueing/scheduling system with dependencies between the individual tasks. To be more specific:

task_0, task_1, task_2, ... task 10 arrive at the queue. Tasks are http requests.

I want to send task_2 only if task_0 is completed. task_1 can be sent without expecting 
task_1 to complete but task_2 has to wait.

Ideas? Models that already exist and match this description?

Comment: What's wrong with using a queue or do you need to be able to process `task_3` before `task_2` because it does not depend on others but 2 is held up because of 1?

Comment: How does task_2 tell you that it depends on task_0?  The usual tactic is that task_0 is something that requires later things to happen, and whatever processes task_0 will add things to the queue as its last step.

Comment: @btilly, let's assume that the message that are dependent have the same destination endpoint

Comment: Are you looking for a cross-platform solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The queue can be topologically sorted.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/topological-sorting.shtml

Comment: I'm out of votes for today, but I'd totally give this a +1 if I weren't.  This is exactly the way to think about this.

Comment: Agreed, definitely figure out the topological sorting. It's not that hard to roll your own.

Comment: OP specified the dependency was on COMPLETION of the predecessor task, not dequeuing, which might be separated in time. If this is a shared work queue (with concurrent worker threads), then topological sorting only helps if the predecessor tasks remain in the queue and have some logic to prevent dependent tasks from being dequeued or executed.